# displaydata function in ex3 coursera machine learning

Tags: octave

I am facing a issue, here is my script. some end or bracket issue but I have checked noting is missing.

```
function [h, display_array] = displayData(X, example_width)

%DISPLAYDATA Display 2D data in a nice grid

%   [h, display_array] = DISPLAYDATA(X, example_width) displays 2D data

%   stored in X in a nice grid. It returns the figure handle h and the 

%   displayed array if requested.



% Set example_width automatically if not passed in

if ~exist('example_width', 'var') || isempty(example_width) 

       example_width = round(sqrt(size(X, 2)));

end

% Gray Image

colormap(gray);

% Compute rows, cols
[m n] = size(X);

example_height = (n / example_width);


% Compute number of items to display
display_rows = floor(sqrt(m));
display_cols = ceil(m / display_rows);

% Between images padding
pad = 1;

% Setup blank display
display_array = - ones(pad + display_rows * (example_height + pad), ...

                   pad + display_cols * (example_width + pad));

% Copy each example into a patch on the display array
curr_ex = 1;

for j = 1:display_rows
    for i = 1:display_cols
            if curr_ex > m, 
                    break; 
            end
% Copy the patch

% Get the max value of the patch

           max_val = max(abs(X(curr_ex, :)));

           display_array(pad + (j - 1) * (example_height + pad) + 
  (1:example_height), ...

                         pad + (i - 1) * (example_width + pad) + 
  (1:example_width)) = ...

                                       reshape(X(curr_ex, :), 
  example_height, example_width) / max_val;

           curr_ex = curr_ex + 1;

   end

   if curr_ex > m, 

           break; 

   end

end


% Display Image

h = imagesc(display_array, [-1 1]);



% Do not show axis

axis image off

drawnow;



end
```

ERROR:

displayData
parse error near line 86 of file C:\Users\ALI\displayData.m

syntax error

Pls guide which is the error in the script, this script is already written in 
the coursera so its must be error free.

Comment: Share the *complete* error message. Please remove redundant spaces and indent your code properly

Comment: I improved the formatting of your question.

Comment: It's very likely that you made an error with the linebreaks around .... If you say "it must be error free" because you have it from coursera, why don't you include a link where you got that file? For example this here works: https://github.com/rieder91/MachineLearning/blob/master/Exercise%203/ex3/displayData.m an of course you have to include the full error message and also mark the linenumber. Without that it's a real pita to help

Comment: @zx485 Your edit has introduced syntax errors and made it so that there is no line 86 to associate with the error.

Comment: @beaker: Ok, maybe I made a mistake. I rolled-back the edit. But why didn't you do the rollback if you noticed that something was wrong? OR even improved the edit and corrected my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have modified the code, and moved the "ellipsis" operator (i.e. `...`) or the line that is supposed to follow it, in several places compared to the original code in coursera.

Since the point of the ellipsis operator is to appear at the end of a line, denoting that the line that follows is meant to be a continuation of the line before, then moving either the ellipsis or the line below it will break the code.

E.g.

```
a = 1 + ...      % correct use of ellipsis, code continues below
    2            % treated as one line, i.e. a = 1 + 2
```

vs

```
a = 1 +          % without ellipsis, the line is complete, and has an error
... 2            % bad use of ellipsis; also anything to the right of '...' is ignored
```

vs

```
a = 1 + ...      % ellipsis used properly so far
                 % but the empty line here makes the whole 'line' `a = 1 +` which is wrong
2                % This is a new instruction
```

Comment: That was apparently part of the edit. In the original code, the ellipses are in their proper places.

Comment: @beaker yes I spotted that too and edited accordingly. Seems there is extra vertical space after the ellipsis in many places that are not in the original file from coursera.